# XQuery tokenize strings with single and multiple values

Tags: function, xquery, tokenize

I have the following XML file:

```
<layout>
 <layout-structure>
  <layout-root id="layout-root">
    <layout-chunk id="header-text">
         <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.01"/>
         <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.02"/>
    </layout-chunk>
    <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03"/>
  </layout-root>
  <layout-root id="layout-root-two">
    <layout-chunk id="header-text-two">
     <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.04"/>
     <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.05"/>
     <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.06"/>
    </layout-chunk>
  <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.07"/>
 </layout-root>
</layout-structure>

<realization>
  <text xref="lay-1.01 lay-1.04"/>
  <text xref="lay-1.02 lay-1.05"/>
  <graphics xref="lay-1.03 lay-1.06" type="1"/>
  <graphics xref="lay-1.07" type="2"/>
</realization>
</layout>
```

I want to extract the values for the *xref* attribute of the **graphics** element, in order to limit the output in the *for* clause of the function shown below.

```
declare function local:gfx($root, $graphics) {
let $graphic-xrefs := tokenize($graphics/@xref, " ")
for $layout-leafs in $root//layout-leaf[@xref = $graphic-xrefs]
return concat('"', $layout-leafs/@xref, '" ', $dotgraphics, ';', $newline) 
};
```

This, however, causes an error because some of the *xref* attributes under the **graphics** element contain a single value, as in the case of `<graphics xref="lay-1.07"/>`.

Is it possible to use tokenize to fetch the **graphics**/*xref* values, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the way you create `$graphic-xrefs`...

```
declare function local:gfx($root, $graphics) {
    let $graphic-xrefs := 
        for $xref in $graphics/@xref
        return
            tokenize($xref,' ')
    for $layout-leafs in $root//layout-leaf[@xref = $graphic-xrefs]
    return concat('"', $layout-leafs/@xref, '" ', $dotgraphics, ';', $newline) 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not cause a problem, as the `tokenize` will simply return the whole string if the split string is not within the search string.

For dealing with such in general a normal `if (...) then ... else ...` statement might be useful. Additionally you might want to use the `try { ... } catch {...}` construct to handle unexpected conditions.

Your code actually works as expected when I run this:

```
declare variable $t :=
<layout>
 <layout-structure>
  <layout-root id="layout-root">
    <layout-chunk id="header-text">
         <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.01"/>
         <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.02"/>
    </layout-chunk>
    <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03"/>
  </layout-root>
  <layout-root id="layout-root-two">
    <layout-chunk id="header-text-two">
     <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.04"/>
     <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.05"/>
     <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.06"/>
    </layout-chunk>
  <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.07"/>
 </layout-root>
</layout-structure>

<realization>
  <text xref="lay-1.01 lay-1.04"/>
  <text xref="lay-1.02 lay-1.05"/>
  <graphics xref="lay-1.03 lay-1.06" type="1"/>
  <graphics xref="lay-1.07" type="2"/>
</realization>
</layout>;

declare function local:gfx($root, $graphics) {
let $graphic-xrefs := tokenize($graphics/@xref, " ")
for $layout-leafs in $root//layout-leaf[@xref = $graphic-xrefs]
return $layout-leafs/@xref
};

local:gfx($t, $t/realization/graphics[2])
```

Please note, that the last `<layout>` in your code snippet should actually be a closing statement.

Comment: Thanks for your input @dirkk! 

Curiously, I get the following error message in Editix: `A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of tokenize() ("lay-1.03", "lay-1.06")`

Comment: Did this happened when you actually executed my code (or just for your original code)? Because for my code I would be rather surprised. The error message also suggest that indeed the mistake is how you call the  function `local:gfx`: It sounds like $graphics/@xref is not just one single element, but instead a sequence of multiple nodes. But as input for tokenize you have to pass a xs:string and no sequence. I highly recommend to check how you call the function and what variables you pass over. If you want further advide, please post how excactly you call the function.